# How do I prevent text template generator from running on every VS build?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, t4

I have a VS 2019 solution with several projects. There is one project that every other project depends on and I have some T4 templates in that project. The templates are regenerated every time I invoke the Build command (no changes) and therefore all the dependent projects are also rebuilt.

How can I fix this so that the templates are only regenerated when necessary? My project file has the following:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TransformOnBuild>true</TransformOnBuild>
  <OverwriteReadOnlyOutputFiles>true</OverwriteReadOnlyOutputFiles>
  <TransformOutOfDateOnly>true</TransformOutOfDateOnly>
</PropertyGroup>
<Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\TextTemplating\Microsoft.TextTemplating.targets" />
<ItemGroup>
  <None Update="Messages\Messages.tt">
    <Generator>TextTemplatingFileGenerator</Generator>
    <LastGenOutput>Messages.generated.cs</LastGenOutput>
  </None>
  <EmbeddedResource Update="Messages\Messages.de.resx" />
  <EmbeddedResource Update="Messages\Messages.resx">
    <Generator>PublicResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
    <LastGenOutput>Messages.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
  </EmbeddedResource>
</ItemGroup>
<Target Name="CallTransformOnBuild" BeforeTargets="CoreCompile">
  <CallTarget Targets="TransformDuringBuild" />
</Target>
```

I only want the transform to run on build if:

- Messages.Generated.cs doesn't exist
- Messages.tt changed
- Messages.resx changed

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure the following XML Tags' are set to false.

```
<TransformOnBuild>False</TransformOnBuild>
<OverwriteReadOnlyOutputFiles>False</OverwriteReadOnlyOutputFiles>
```